# Criar um Calculador de Senha

Tags: delphi

Primeiramente sou iniciante em Delphi e tomei como iniciativa primaria realizar um programa para auxiliar em meu trabalho, pois na aplicação que utilizo a senha varia diariamente em duas situações que direi à seguir:

O cálculo da primeira senha é simples, basicamente: `(dia x mês) + 2012`

Já o calculo da segunda senha é: `((dia x mês) + 2013) + dia`

*obs: lembrando que só vou utilizar um botão para gerar a primeira senha e um para a segunda*

Gostaria de um auxílio sobre como posso realizar esses cálculos no Delphi 7, pois assistindo alguns videos de criar calculadora até deu para se localizar na aplicação, mas não para realizar... a quem puder ajudar...grato desde já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode realizar calculo simples de matemática para isto, o que você precisa é decodificar a data atual para extrair os dados necessários.

Na `System.DateUtils` existe uma função para isto.

Ex para o primeiro calculo:

```
var
  vDia: Word;
  vMes: Word;
  vAno: Word;
  vSenha: string;
begin
  // Dia, mês e ano separado
  DecodeDate(Now, vAno, vMes, vDia);

  // Cálculo simples
  vSenha := IntToStr((vDia * vMes) + 2012);
end;
```

Comment: era exatamente isso que procurava, uma maneira simples de entender como funcionaria no cálculo... agradeço bastante a ajuda!